# Unable to get hidden field value in validation script

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Trying to do validations (unique) for add and edit.

I am unable to retrive hidden field value in my validations jquery script.

Following is javascript:

//included : 'jquery.validate.min',  -- these files included

**validate_branch.js**

```
var validator = $('#form_add_branch').validate({
    errorElement: 'div',
    rules: {
        branch_name: {
            required: true,
            ValidateComma: true,
            remote: BASE_URL_PATH+ "learner/branch/is_branch_exists?branch_id="+$('#branch_id').val()
        }
    },
    messages: {
        branch_name: {
            required: languageArray['branch_name_required'],
            ValidateComma: languageArray['branch_name_comma'],
            remote: languageArray['branch_name_exists']
        }
    }
});


/* Comma validation (Comma not allowed)
 * 
 * @param value String
 * 
 * @return boolean
 * 
 */
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ValidateComma", function(value) {
    var filter = /[,]+/;
    if (filter.test(value))
    {
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}, languageArray['branch_name_comma']);
```

This is how we calling validations:

```
<script>
    $("#btn_add_branch").on("click", function() {  
        $('#form_add_branch').validate();
        if ($('#form_add_branch').valid()) {
            var branch_name = $('#branch_name').val();
            var branch_id = $('#branch_id').val();
            $.post(BASE_URL_PATH + "learner/branch/add_branch", {branch_name: branch_name, branch_id: branch_id}, function(data, status) {
                if (data != "false") {
                    $("#succ_msg").show();
                    $("#err_msg").hide();
                    $('#branch_name').val("");
                    $('#branch_id').val("");
                } else {
                    $("#succ_msg").hide();
                    $("#err_msg").show();
                }


            });
        }
    });

    function edit_branch(branch_id) {
        BRANCH_ID = branch_id;
        $.post(BASE_URL_PATH + "learner/branch/get_branch_name", {branch_id: branch_id}, function(data, status) {
            if (data) {
                $('#branch_name').val(data);
                $('#branch_id').val(branch_id);
            }
        });
    }



</script>
```

**Note** : In remote `$('#branch_id').val()` this comes blank, *but at server side it comes*.
Please guide me in right way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **[`ignore`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore)** property in your `validate` method. By default `hidden inputs` are not validated by `jquery.validate.js` and thus you need to override this behavior using

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
  ignore: [] //do not ignore any input fields even though its hidden
});
```

The above method sets that behavior for all the `elements` irrespective of which `forms` you have `validation`. Now if you want to **[`ignore`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore)** just one field, then you can do it as below:

```
var validator = $('#form_add_branch').validate({
      ignore: ":hidden:not('#branch_id')" //ignore all hidden fields except #branch_id
});
```